# Workflow for developing Golang command-line

Tags: vim, go

I'm looking to build my first Go command-line app. I feel really out of sorts...What would the typical workflow look like when doing something like that?

I'm attempting to write some go and then I run `go build` in vim and attempt to run the program with another terminal tab, but `go build` alone doesn't seem to build the program and install it on my system. I tried with the `-i` and that worked the first time, but didn't update it after.

I'm sure it's silly, but hopefully you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: My workflow is: `go build . && go install`. Seems to work fine on my Mac anyway.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: why the `go build`? It just throws away the intermediate objects, and if you have a main package, you end up with an extra binary in your working directory. `go install` does what `go build` does, plus installs everything it built.

Comment: Habit I guess. I generally `go build` first and run it within the current dir first. Then I `go install` when I want to run it everywhere. I just got into the habit of doing both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go build` && `go install` did the trick!

Comment: you don't need `go build`. `go install` does everything `go build`, plus it will install any dependencies, making subsequent invocations faster.

Comment: Thanks. Does `go build` just build it and put it in the local directory?

Comment: Yes. Your command builds 2 separate binaries, one in `$PWD` and one bin `$GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: I settled on just using `go build` and running the executable from the local dir. There's no worry doing just that is there?